# How to package Python Microservice to use in internal for other Services?

Tags: python, microservices, fastapi, python-packaging, python-poetry

Im currently building a python project with microservices architecture. Each service consists of different "modules" / folders. Some other microservices can use a client from a service to make calls to the service.

The folder structure is the following

[image]

How do I create a package that contains users.users_client, users._users_core ....

The github is used by Github Actions and the requirements.txt and app.yaml are used from Google Cloud App Engine.

The service runs with gunicorn / uvicorn. So I need to make sure the service is still runnable when changing the folder structure.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but to create a package you simply move the folders into a folder (users) with an init(py) file and change your imports where needed. It seems more idiomatic to drop the users_ prefixes

Comment: Isnt this kinda strange to have a folder called users with a users folder insinde and then different modules ?

Comment: Not really, the top level folder is usually just a container of a project that holds more than just source code, its contents not necessarily being equal to what is included in build- or release artifacts. [Django's project structure](https://github.com/django/django) is pretty typical

Comment: But I have each service in a different repository and then have users repository with a folder called users makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: I don't think I understand your project structure, binding and goals